# Create new array by matching values passed in url using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am building a web application that is primarily using Tableau elements (filters, visualizations, etc.) and the problem I have run into is in passing a large amount (dynamic) of filtered parameters across web pages. I've been trying to work with the JavaScript below, but not having any luck.

```
function getFilterd()
{
    var worksheets = vizFilter.getWorkbook().getActiveSheet().getWorksheets();
    var prjArray = window.location.search.substring(1).split(',');
    var newArray = [];

    //Run through field/filter names
    var displayFilters = function (filters) {
        for (var i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
            filterName = filters[i].getFieldName();

            //If field/filter name == PRJECT then store selected values in an array
            if (filterName == 'PRJECT') {
                filterList = []
                for (var z = 0; z < filters[i].getAppliedValues().length; z++) {
                    filterList[z] = filters[i].getAppliedValues()[z].value;
                }

                //Compare filterList values to prjArray and push to newArray if a match
                for (var t = 0; t < filterList.length; t++) {
                    if (filterList[t].getAppliedValues()[t].value.substring(4) == prjArray) {
                        newArray.push(filterList[t]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

    //Runs through each worksheet in active workbook (optional) 
    for (var worksheetIndex = 0; worksheetIndex < worksheets.length; worksheetIndex++){ 
    worksheets[worksheetIndex].getFiltersAsync().then(displayFilters); 
    }   
}
```

Comment: please add some examples of `worksheet`, `window.location.search` and other missing parts.

Comment: Let me provide more description as to what I'm trying to accomplish. Due to the large number of parameters I'm trying to pass in url, I have been able to reduce the parameters themselves to just the last 4 characters. The intent is to then extract the array of last 4 characters and match the full set of parameters to the array containing last 4 characters. If they are a match then the parameter should get pushed to a new array. I don't get any errors, but getting an empty array also :(

Comment: Nina the window.location.search line should be extracting the array of last 4 characters from the url. The worksheet line is in reference to the Tableau javascript api.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a `split()` on `window.location.search.substring(1)`, you return an array. Here, you are comparing a substring against an array, and that is always going to return false.

```
if (filterList[t].getAppliedValues()[t].value.substring(4) == prjArray) {
    newArray.push(filterList[t]);
}
```

Additionally, you are only putting values into `filterList` and trying to access them with `getAppliedValues` is not going to work.

You need to test if the substring is within the array. You can do this using `includes()` to determine if the array includes the value provided.

```
if (prjArray.includes(filterList[t].substring(4))) { 
    newArray.push(filterList[t]);
}
```

The `includes()` method is [not completely supported by all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). If you need backward compatibility,you can do this using `indexOf` and test is it returns other than `-1`

```
if (prjArray.indexOf(filterList[t].substring(4)) !== -1) { 
    newArray.push(filterList[t]);
}
```

Comment: I'm still struggling with this as I have not yet been able to return anything into an array and I'm thinking it's because javascript is not recognizing any matches. For additional reference the format of filterList is something similar to '0713AX95' where prjArray has a format of 'AX95'. Ultimately i'm trying to build an array to include anything from filterList that contains the last 4 characters matching anything from prjArray.

Comment: @MikeSummons Updated answer because there was more wrong than just the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

So I was finally able to figure this out. The logic below was incorrect as mentioned by Justin in his answer:

```
            //Compare filterList values to prjArray and push to newArray if a match
            for (var t = 0; t < filterList.length; t++) {
                if (filterList[t].getAppliedValues()[t].value.substring(4) == prjArray) {
                    newArray.push(filterList[t]);
                }
            }
```

In addition, were some syntax errors in the if statement. The following is the revised statement that did return the desired array:

```
//Compare filterList values to prjArray and push to newArray if a match
newArray = []
for (var t = 0; t < filterList.length; t++){
    if (prjArray.indexOf(filterList[t].substring(4)) != -1) { 
        newArray.push(filterList[t]);
    };
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I missed that problem and had just corrected my answer as I saw yours. :)